# cross entropy is nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, cross-entropy

I am deploying my conv-deconv net. My question is the cross entropy was always nan while training so the solver didn't update the weights. I checked my code all day but I didn't know where did I go wrong. The following is my architecture:
[image]
here is my cross entropy function

```
ys_reshape = tf.reshape(ys,[-1,1])
prediction = tf.reshape(relu4,[-1,1])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-(ys_reshape*tf.log(prediction)))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

where the dimension of ys is [1,500,500,1], ys_reshape is [250000,1], relu4 is [1,500,500,1] and prediction is [250000,1]. The value of label matrix, ys are {0,1}, which is a two categories dense prediction.

If I print train_step out it would display None. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did a great job of narrowing the problem down to the right couple of lines of code.

So your predicted probability is directly the output of `ReLU4`?

There are two problems with that.

First: it can be greater than one.

Second:

It can be exactly zero (Anywhere the input to `ReLU4` is negative, it's output will be zero).

`log(0) -> NaN`

The usual approach to this is to treat the linear activations (No ReLU) as the log-odds of each class.

A naive implementation is always broken (numerical issues).

Since you have a single class, you should use [tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)

---

And for the training op returning `None`: There is a subtle distinction here, between ops and tensors. Try `print(train_step)` and `print(cross_entropy)`.

Evaluating an op does something, while evaluating a tensor gets you a value. So if you're looking for the value of the cross entropy that was calculated on the forward pass, just do something like `_, loss_value = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy])`

Comment: Thank @mdaoust for pointing me out my mistakes!

For your first question, yes the predicted probability is the output from relu4.
So in the diogram, loss=cross_etropy.

I forgot that there would be many zeros after the relu operation.
now I replace the third line with cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,ys_reshape)

But my  train_step outputs still are None. So I think  the error in this layer is fixed but there are some remaining errors in other layers. Thank you so so much whatever!!

Comment: Yes I want to observe the cross_entropy matrix after every forward passing and it finally works!! I use this command: _, loss_value = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy],feed_dict={xs:batch_xs, ys:batch_ys}). 
Thank you and you are the best!! Thank you so so so much!!! But I am still a little confused that why the output of print(train_step) is None?! In my opinion, it should display something like tensor object or tensor class rather than None. But the most important is you solve my problem ~